# Calling 3rd level categories of current category

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

I am trying to call all subcategories of the current category and grab their subcategories (3rd level).

I am using the following code to call all children of the current category:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->setOrder('name', 'asc')
?>

    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <div>
          <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img class="" src="" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
          <div>
          <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><h3><?php echo $category->getName() ?></h3></a>
          <hr>
          <a href=""><p></p></a> // Want 3rd level categories listed here
          </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This gives me a nice list of all the subcagetories of the current category but **how would I insert the 3rd level categories inside this part?**

```
          <a href=""><p></p></a>
```

Trying to accomplish a list like this:

```
Clothing
   Shirts
   Shoes
Accessories
   Scarfs
   Jewelry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something else but got the result I needed.

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 4;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
<div>
    <div>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
           <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><img class=""  src="" /></a>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><h3><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></h3></a>
                <hr>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><p><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></p></a>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
->setOrder('name', 'asc')
?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img class="" src="" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
  <div>
  <?php if($category->getLevel()==3):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><p><?php echo $category->getName() ?></p></a> // Want 3rd level categories listed here
  <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><h3><?php echo $category->getName() ?></h3></a>

  <?php endif;?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It shows the subcategory of the current category. So it looks like this: 

`Clothing
Clothing`

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: Still not showing 3rd level categories, unfortunately. I will soldier on with this conundrum until I find a working solution :-)